# Overlay won't let me click the images HTML

Tags: html, css

The overlay won't let me click the images. When I remove the overlay, I can click.

```html
<div class="image">
  <A HREF="Carta-Apotheke.pdf" class="image__img" target="_blank">
    <img src="img/A.png" alt="Image" height="375" width="225" alt="Reserva">
  </a>
  <div class="image__overlay image__overlay--blur">
    <div class="image__title">Cart</div>
    <p class="image__description"> Here we have a brick wall.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

```css
.image__overlay {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
    color: #ffffff;
    font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 1s;
}

.image__overlay--blur {
    backdrop-filter: blur(5px);
}
```

Comment: CSS

.image__overlay {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
    color: #ffffff;
    font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 1s;
}

.image__overlay--blur {
    backdrop-filter: blur(5px);
}

Comment: You can edit the question to put more detail in, instead of using comments. Please update the question with enough to demonstrate the problem

Comment: What is your actual question?

Answer (score 2):

The clicks are hitting the overlay instead of the image. If you don't want that you can set `pointer-events: none;` on the overlay to let them through.

[MDN: CSS pointer-events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events)

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because the overlay you set is actually overlapping the image and making you unable to click the image.

In normal terms, the image is actually behind the overlay so you are unable to click it.

This will fix your problem;

```
.image__overlay {
    <!-- The previous code -->
    z-index: -1;
}

img {
    z-index: 1;
}
```

This will put the image in front of the overlay so you can click it.